# Unable to complete setup CyanogenMod 12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-services

I recently flashed CyanogenMod Nightly 12.1 on my YU Yuphoria, followed by ARM64 Micro Open GApps package. When I booted after successfully flashing, I had to do the system setup which is to be done anytime when the data is reset. I almost completed it but when I reached the step where I need to sign into my Google Account, it shows

```
Checking info..
```

And then in 1-2 seconds I get an error screen saying

```
Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped.
```

What could be the reason behind it? I'm not able to complete the system setup and use my custom ROM.

Comment: Its incompatible GApps problem. Try some other. The details you gave are not sufficient to reach a relevant decision.?

Comment: I was confused before flashing.. My YU Yuphoria is a 64-bit device but I wasn't sure whether the CM nightly is 32-bit based or 64-bit based.. So I asked on the official YU forums, and they asked me to download the ARM64 Micro Package..

Comment: What happens if you tell it to skip, then finish the start up process it, Then go into the settings and add the account from there?

Comment: @jer3my I thought of doing it but then I wouldn't have been able to restore the data (settings, WiFi passwords etc) saved in my Google account..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved..

The problem persisted only till the time I had been using Open GApps.. Then I checked out for GApps on [the official CyanogenMod website](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) and got an idea to try CGApps instead of Open GApps.. So I downloaded the ARM64 package of CGApps and flashed it.. Thankfully it worked for me.. So if someone's facing problems with Open GApps, CGApps is definitely worth a try..

Comment: Mark your own response as "answer"

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't get you.. Do you mean I shall mark my answer as my accepted answer to the question?

Comment: That is correct.